# Material UI Vertical tabs - Menu content hidden by tab content

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I have this example of vertical tab Material UI in React where content of one tab is a long string.

In this case it is overlaying menu on the left because of that long content. Why is this happening?

Expected behavior is that content is just squeezed inside that `TabPanel`.
If you change to another tab with less content, menu is back and fully visible.

**Hiding menu:**
[image]

**Showing menu:**
[image]

Here is codesandbox forked from official one:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-vertical-tabs-content-overflowing-menu-0v6pb?file=/demo.js

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `overflow: visible` to `tabs` css rule

```
tabs: {
    borderRight: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    overflow: 'visible',
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try